# VBA: Ubound function

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get the values from my table, I have the error in this line

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Num_Ligne, 5), Cells(Num_Ligne, 5)).Resize(UBound(Tblo, 1), UBound(Tblo, 2)) = Tblo
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: you are probably getting an error on that line, use: `ActiveSheet.Cells(Num_Ligne, 5).Resize(UBound(Tblo, 1), UBound(Tblo, 2)) = Tblo`

Comment: Yes, I get the error on this line

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the error

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work: ActiveSheet.Cells(Num_Ligne, 5).Resize(UBound(Tblo, 1), UBound(Tblo, 2)) = Tblo

Comment: try `ActiveSheet.Cells(Num_Ligne, 5).Resize(UBound(Tblo, 1)+1, UBound(Tblo, 2)+1) = Tblo`

Comment: did you try my code in my last comment?  It should do what you want, based on what you are showing.

Comment: Thank you! It works, could you explain me your code please?

Comment: Your array is base `0` not base `1` so we needed to make an adjustment to the return of the UBound to correct for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !